# Java Vector wrong output

Tags: java, vector, output

My problem is, when I add for example 3 inputs in Vector and when I display the result I only found the last output.

XMLTable, Table,Column = classes

cols : the vector who contain the problem

Code :

```
btnSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            XMLTable xt= new XMLTable();
            Table table = new Table();
            Column col = new Column();
            Vector<String> txtF = new Vector<String>();
            Vector<String> comboF = new Vector<String>();
            Vector<Column> cols = new Vector<Column>();
            Component[] comp = columns.getComponents();
            for(Component c : comp){
                if (c instanceof JTextField){
                    txtF.add(((JTextField) c).getText());
                    //col.setName(((JTextField) c).getText());  
                }
                else if(c instanceof JComboBox){
                    comboF.add(((JComboBox<String>) c).getSelectedItem().toString());
                    //col.setType(((JComboBox<String>) c).getSelectedItem().toString());
                }

            }
            for(int i=0; i<txtF.size();i++){
                col.setName(txtF.get(i));
                //System.out.println("NAMEE: "+txtF.get(i));
                col.setType(comboF.get(i));
                //System.out.println("Type: "+comboF.get(i));
                cols.add(col);
            }


            for(int i=0;i<cols.size();i++){                 
                System.out.println("Column : "+i);
                System.out.println("name : "+cols.elementAt(i).getName());
                System.out.println("type : "+cols.elementAt(i).getType());
            }
```

INPUT :

```
name : a  Type : String
name : b  Type : Numeric
name : c  Type : String
```

OUTPUT :

```
Column : 0
name : c
type : String
Column : 1
name : c
type : String
Column : 2
name : c
type : String
```

Comment: Vector is obsolete so unless you *have to* use it, you should switch to another collection such as ArrayList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the same object to `cols` over and over again since `col` is always the same object. Keep in mind that you handle objects by references (even though [Java is always pass-by-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value), if you pass an object to a method, you actually pass the object-reference, not the object itself). To fix this, remove the declaration of `Column col = ...` in the fifth line and change the second `for loop` to this:

```
[...]
for(int i=0; i<txtF.size();i++){
    Column col = new Column(); // Declaration moved to here
    col.setName(txtF.get(i));
    //System.out.println("NAMEE: "+txtF.get(i));
    col.setType(comboF.get(i));
    //System.out.println("Type: "+comboF.get(i));
    cols.add(col);
}
[...]
```

This should fix your problem.